# Change page title dynamically before header is rendered

Tags: title, wp-title

Hi I am trying to change the page title prior to `wp_head` being rendered:

```
$pdf_link = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'pdf/generate_pdf.php?type=single&event_id=' . $id . '&uid=' . $_GET['individual_result']; 

function updateTitle() {
    global $title;

    function wpdocs_filter_wp_title(  ) {
        return 'new title';
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpdocs_filter_wp_title', 10, 2 );

    $title = 'new title';
}
add_action( 'init', 'updateTitle' );
```

Though is not working, any ideas?